# How can I completely reset audio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My problem started out as just it saying it was playing from a fake device and there were no others. I tried like 50 ways to fix it and now it says I have more audio devices than I have and will only play through external audio.

If normal audio was 4k then this is a 4x4 screen - very janky - and every way I tried to fix this seemed to make it worse.

Trying to reinstall it did nothing.

A live cd seemed to work.

I don't want to reinstall but I want my audio to be in every way the same as after a fresh install.

Drivers do not matter that much as I think this device only gets the most generic of all drivers from Intel cause it's never got any new drivers after the installation.

How can I completely reset audio?

If hope this helps I saw a lot of red when doing it so I'm guessing it might tell
you how it's broken, Also sorry for formating
Oops this happened
Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 79730.
You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 8 links.
so here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F8kJrNESy5f3ANZ70OEobJ0B8_cQcbbh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please list the 50 things you tried so no one give you the same suggestions.

Comment: Oof no idea my history auto-reset and my google history is missing everything but I basically the first 10 things on 30 different searches The olny thing I don't want to lose are my apps though,      But I Think the Ones I Have tried to reset so far and it didn't work are pulse auido and alsa beyond that no idea cause I tryied a lot of things I added some thing that might help as the sound troubleshooting on guide on the help.ubnuntu website but no idea afterward